# How do you get all the children of specific ref in firebase into an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

Here is my Firebase structure.

[image]

I want to get it all back like so.

```
 {
"users": {
    "EFo7BemCuWVFyGYwk0CiTHR5fDB2": {
        "profile": {
            "-LMUD--2APhiSLkEtVbM": {
                "profileName": "bob",
                "profilePic": "https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c27.0.160.160/p160x160/205110_1018814483408_6876_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=2e40387a728c2f8c8d04b3299601be7e&oe=5C18FC6D",
                "score": 73,
                "teamName": "lzs"
            }
        },
        "team": {
            "-LPpWX5o8kmfCKUZBoYy": {
                "competitorKey": "-LNb6AEdyBSmeooeDhT0"
            },
            "-LPpWX_SMWHWsKauutVC": {
                "competitorKey": "-LNb42VDA4ZjW2EeVLLd"
            }
        }
    },
    "FIXBObMxXoOzFE7hsb4wHl8esfe2": {
        "profile": {
            "-LPqBizyqR-jEAsawYO7": {
                "profileName": "steve",
                "profilePic": "http://www.cricearena.com/images/rough_riders_new_medium_logo-u2182.png",
                "score": 43,
                "teamName": "twitterRangers4"
            }
        },
        "team": {
            "-LPqX9ncuK09WvnT3SIk": {
                "competitorKey": "-LNb6AEdyBSmeooeDhT0"
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

All i get back though is the keys in users.

My redux action is

```
export function loadLeague() {
 return dispatch => {
leagueFireDB.path = `users/`;
leagueFireDB.subscribe(dispatch);
 };
}
```

My high level fb db function.

```
    subscribe(emit) {
let ref = firebaseDb.ref(this._path);
let initialized = false;
let list = [];

ref.once('value', () => {
  initialized = true;
  console.log("ONCE::",this._actions)
  emit(this._actions.onLoad(list));
});

ref.on('child_added', snapshot => {
  if (initialized) {
    emit(this._actions.onAdd(this.unwrapSnapshot(snapshot)));
  }
  else {
    list.push(this.unwrapSnapshot(snapshot));
  }
});

ref.on('child_changed', snapshot => {
  emit(this._actions.onChange(this.unwrapSnapshot(snapshot)));
});

ref.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
  console.log("REMOVE2::",snapshot)
  emit(this._actions.onRemove(this.unwrapSnapshot(snapshot)));
});

this._unsubscribe = () => ref.off();
}
```

So obviously it hits the 'users' node in the DB, grabs those keys there.  It doesn't traverse and return everything that is a child of the ref (or i guess the grand kids, etc).  Im looking to get all the children of the Users ref in the db but I've been looking around, haven't found anything that does that.  Im react redux firebase.  Thats it.  No API/middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this gives me the full object, including all children and grand children like I was looking for.

```
 subscribeChild(emit) {
   let ref = firebaseDb.ref(this._path);
   ref.once('value', snapshot => {
   emit(this._actions.onLoad(this.unwrapSnapshot(snapshot)));
   });
 }
```

here is the unwrap I have have.

```
 unwrapSnapshot(snapshot) {
   let attrs = snapshot.val();
   attrs.key = snapshot.key;
   return new this._modelClass(attrs);
 }
```

My load action request was calling the ref.once high level firebase db call but I was not unwrapping the snapshot there.  So I created another subscribe emitter called subscribeChild just for this load request and put the unwrapSnapShot in the emit it returns.  Sure enough the entire object has all child ref's and key value data included. Now i have to figure out how to hand the data object. :)

I'm just nudging my way through this firebase RTDB so if anyone has comments or if I'm truly doing this wrong, please comment, I'll update or accept better answers accordingly.